# counting number of occurrences in table 1 where date is between date in table 2

Tags: sql

I have two tables with a date col and an id col

Table 1:

```
Date1           ID
2017-01-10      1
2016-02-12      1
2017-12-12      2
...
```

Table 2:

```
Date2            ID
2016-04-10       1
2018-01-10       1
2017-01-01       2
```

I want to merge these tables such that I get a third column which tells me how many dates in Table 1 occur before the date in table 2, grouped by id. In the case where the date in table 1 occur before multiple date in table 2 with the same id, I want it to be grouped with the earliest date.

This is my desired output:

```
Date2           ID        Count
2016-04-10      1         1
2018-01-10      1         1
2017-01-01      2         0
```

Comment: Why count = 1 for second row? There are two id = 1 rows in t1 with a date before 2018-01-10.

Answer (score 0):

The following query returns number of t1 dates before the t2 date, for same id.

```
select t2.date2, t2.id, count(t1.id)
from t2
left join t1
    on t1.id = t2.id and t1.date < t2.date
group by t2.date2, t2.id
```